# Google authentication to access Bigquery from R

Tags: r, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the `bigrquery` package to run query in `Google's Bigquery` with below code -

```
library(bigrquery)
bg_auth("My_Email", "My_Token")
```

Now, once I hit above line of code, R tries to open a browser to authenticate for Google service.

However I am running above code in a GCP instance (with Ubuntu) with no GUI and it doesnt have any active Internet access due to security reason.

So I am interested to know if there is any way to authenticate it offline and access to `Bigquery`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**:

I created a **GCP VM instance** with the **default service account.**

After this, I used the following code to execute a query.

```
library(bigrquery)
bq_auth(use_oob = TRUE)
projectid = "my-project-id"
# Set your query
sql <- "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` LIMIT 10"

# Run the query and store the data in a dataframe
df <- query_exec(sql, projectid, use_legacy_sql = FALSE)

# Print the query result
df
```

Due I'm not using another service account, I used the method **bq_auth(use_oob = TRUE)** to use the default account from the VM instance.

After executing the code with:

```
Rscript mycode.R
```

The code was executed without requesting authentication within the browser.

This is a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery#authenticate_your_request) to use R with Bigquery within Notebooks; however, the implementation should be similar to use it on a GCP VM instance.

Comment: Unfortunately this still require a browser based authentication when you use it first time

Comment: Probably when authentication is done first time using browser, the information may be cashed somewhere in the system. Do you know the location where it saved? If we know this then we can cashe the information in a computer that has internet access and then move that information to the GCP where active internet is barred?

Comment: @Bogaso I'm not able to replicate your scenario, regarding your questions, this seems not to be the right way to resolve the issue, I edited my post, this could help you to clarify how I was able to execute my code without authentication from the browser.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
# https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery
library(bigrquery)

# replace this with your project ID 
billing <- "your_ID" 

sql <- "SELECT * FROM `your_table`"
tb <- bq_project_query(billing, sql)

#> Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
df <- bq_table_download(tb, max_results = 10)

df1 <- data.frame(df)
```

Comment: Well, it still tries to open Browser when I hit bq_project_query() and authenticate through it. You may have already authenticated earlier.

Comment: The last time I used the code was around 1 year ago.  It worked fine for me at the time.  Maybe things are slightly different now.  I don't use GCP anymore; using Azure now.  This line should help you: billing <- "your_ID"